# SQL Query to get information of best scoring players from different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have normalised my database to several tables but will only mention two as they are probably the only ones needed.

One UserDetails with fields, player_ID, firstname, surname and nickname
Another GameDetails with fields, player_ID, Score, Level and Coins

I want to read the UserDetails.nickname, GameDetails.level and GameDetails.score of the people that have the top 10 best scores from the database.

Could I have help on the SQL query I should be using?
Guidance on what keywords I should be using is also welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You should provide sample data and desired results.  Pay particular attention to ties and what to do if one person is in the top 10 more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the tables and a `LIMIT 10` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select u.nickname, g.level, g.score
from UserDetails u inner join GameDetails g
on g.player_ID = u.player_ID
order by g.score desc
limit 10
```

Comment: i tried an inner join before but i didnt know what on. now i know it on the ID and that makes a lot of sense. this has helped thanks i appreciate it.

Comment: `player_ID` is the only column that relates the 2 tables, so the join is based on it.

Comment: If 10th and 11th have the same score then random record will be returned...

Comment: You can change to: `order by g.score desc, u.nickname` if in this case you want the rows ordered by nickname.